# Удалить все последующие одинаковые записи

Tags: golang

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Signal int

type State int

type Transition struct {
    InitialState *State
    CurrentState *State
    Input        *Signal
    Output       *Signal
}

func (a *Transition) findByOutputInRange(b []Transition) []*Transition {
    var result []*Transition
    for i := range b {
        if a.Output == b[i].Output && a.Output != nil {
            result = append(result, &b[i])
        }
    }
    return result
}

type Machine struct {
    States      map[string]*State
    Inputs      map[string]*Signal
    Outputs     map[string]*Signal
    Transitions []Transition
}

func (m *Machine) minimize() {
    for i := 0; i < len(m.Transitions); i++ {
        for j := range m.Transitions[i].findByOutputInRange(m.Transitions[i+1:]) {
            fmt.Println(&m.Transitions[25])
            fmt.Println(m.Transitions[j])
            fmt.Println()
        }
    }
}

var (
    states  map[string]*State
    inputs  map[string]*Signal
    outputs map[string]*Signal
    machine Machine
)

func init() {
    states = make(map[string]*State)
    for i := 1; i < 26; i++ {
        states[fmt.Sprintf("%v%d", "A", i)] = new(State)
    }

    inputs = make(map[string]*Signal)
    inputs["-"] = nil
    inputs["!X2X4X5"] = new(Signal)
    inputs["X1"] = new(Signal)
    inputs["X6"] = new(Signal)
    inputs["!X6"] = new(Signal)
    inputs["X7"] = new(Signal)
    inputs["!X7"] = new(Signal)
    inputs["!X8"] = new(Signal)
    inputs["X8!X9"] = new(Signal)
    inputs["X8X9"] = new(Signal)

    outputs = make(map[string]*Signal)
    outputs["-"] = nil
    for i := 1; i < 27; i++ {
        outputs[fmt.Sprintf("%v%d", "Y", i)] = new(Signal)
    }

    machine = Machine{
        states,
        inputs,
        outputs,
        []Transition{
            Transition{states["A1"], states["A2"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y1"]},
            Transition{states["A2"], states["A3"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y2"]},
            Transition{states["A3"], states["A4"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y3"]},
            Transition{states["A4"], states["A5"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y4"]},
            Transition{states["A5"], states["A6"], inputs["!X2X4X5"], outputs["Y5"]},
            Transition{states["A5"], states["A1"], inputs["X1"], outputs["-"]},
            Transition{states["A6"], states["A7"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y6"]},
            Transition{states["A7"], states["A8"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y7"]},
            Transition{states["A8"], states["A9"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y8"]},
            Transition{states["A9"], states["A10"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y9"]},
            Transition{states["A10"], states["A11"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y10"]},
            Transition{states["A11"], states["A12"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y11"]},
            Transition{states["A12"], states["A13"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y12"]},
            Transition{states["A13"], states["A14"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y13"]},
            Transition{states["A14"], states["A15"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y14"]},
            Transition{states["A15"], states["A16"], inputs["X6"], outputs["Y15"]},
            Transition{states["A15"], states["A16"], inputs["!X6"], outputs["Y16"]},
            Transition{states["A16"], states["A17"], inputs["X7"], outputs["Y17"]},
            Transition{states["A16"], states["A17"], inputs["!X7"], outputs["Y18"]},
            Transition{states["A17"], states["A18"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y19"]},
            Transition{states["A18"], states["A19"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y20"]},
            Transition{states["A19"], states["A20"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y21"]},
            Transition{states["A20"], states["A21"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y22"]},
            Transition{states["A21"], states["A22"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y23"]},
            Transition{states["A22"], states["A23"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y24"]},
            Transition{states["A23"], states["A14"], inputs["!X8"], outputs["Y13"]},
            Transition{states["A23"], states["A14"], inputs["X8!X9"], outputs["Y25"]},
            Transition{states["A23"], states["A14"], inputs["X8X9"], outputs["-"]},
            Transition{states["A24"], states["A25"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y26"]},
            Transition{states["A25"], states["A26"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y27"]},
            Transition{states["A26"], states["A1"], inputs["-"], outputs["Y28"]},
        },
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(&machine.Transitions[25])
    fmt.Println(
        machine.Transitions[13].findByOutputInRange(machine.Transitions[13+1:])[0],
    )
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println()
    machine.minimize()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Wu8UERbMhb).

Метод minimize должен удалять одинаковые записи из machine.Transition (записи Transition считаются одинаковыми если у них одинаковое поле Output). 
Т.е. из массива machine.Transition должна быть удалена следующая запись: 
`Transition{states["A23"], states["A14"], inputs["!X8"], outputs["Y13"]}` (индекс 25).

В main метод findByOutputInRange работает так как требуется - возвращает массив Transition с одинаковыми Transition.Output. В методе minimize все ломается это можно увидеть в логах.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не могу понять почему так происходит. Где то я не правильно использую указатели, но не знаю где.

Comment: Вы вывалили полторы страницы кода и при этом не написали, что значит "оно ломается". Редуцируйте код до участка, где ломается, и опишите проблему нормально.

Comment: Как раз я и не пойму в каком месте поэтому привел весь код. А суть проблемы в том что функция findByOutputInRange работает по разному если вызывать ее из main.main и main.minimize. Поэтому я полагаю что я не правильно использую указатели (но не знаю где)

Answer (score 1):

```
for j := range m.Transitions[i].findByOutputInRange(m.Transitions[i+1:]) {
    fmt.Println(&m.Transitions[25])
    fmt.Println(m.Transitions[j])
```

У вас тут `j` - это индекс. Индекс результата.

```
res := m.Transitions[i].findByOutputInRange(m.Transitions[i+1:])
for j := range res {
    fmt.Println(&m.Transitions[25])
    fmt.Println(res[j])
```

или

```
for _, t := range m.Transitions[i].findByOutputInRange(m.Transitions[i+1:]) {
    fmt.Println(&m.Transitions[25])
    fmt.Println(t)
```

делайте. Про то, что у вас алгоритм квадратичный вообще молчу.